# MVC 4 JsonResult - method or operation is not implemented

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, jsonresult

I have a JsonResult method that I am trying to call with jQuery Ajax but I am getting a 500 server error with the runtime error message of this:

```
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

This is my jQuery:

```
function submitPanel(value) {
    var panelIds = [];
    $('#' + value + ' select ').each(function () {
        panelIds.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'SavePanel',
        data: {
            chairId: panelIds[0],
            coPanelistId: panelIds[1]
        },
        type: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#InterviewManagementFrm').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

panelIds[0] and panelIds[1] have guids because I have been using alerts to check.

```
public JsonResult SavePanel(Guid chairId, Guid coPanelistId)
        {
            DataLayer.InterviewManagement.InterviewManagementDataLayer DataLayer = new InterviewManagementDataLayer();
            //DataLayer.SavePanel(new Guid(chairId), new Guid(coPanelistId));

            // TODO: success/failure logic returned from data layer method
            var json_string = "{ success: \"true\" }";
            return Json(json_string, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This JsonResult method is in my controller, it isn't doing alot but when it works it will be talking to my data layer.

Have I forgotten to write a line of code or is there something else I am missing?

**response header**

```
Remote Address:::1:58719
Request URL:http://localhost:58719/InterviewManagement/SavePanel
Request Method:JSON
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:94
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:58719
Origin:http://localhost:58719
Referer:http://localhost:58719/InterviewManagement/InterviewManagementPage
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
chairId:6fe262de-a5b3-4c20-8b76-fab25ccd88ec
coPanelistId:72e42a86-cc98-45f0-9950-2b009ad0ec5d
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Close
Content-Length:10399
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 21 May 2014 14:11:34 GMT
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
```

Comment: You are calling the wrong URL I think. What is the name of the controller that has SavePanel method?

Comment: Indeed... `SavePanel` translates to `/SavePanel/Index` under MVC

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları, He may have registered a custom route for this...

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, I think the server would return 404 in this case.

Comment: My controller name is InterviewManagementController but this javascript is in a seperate script file. There is no razor available for me there.

Comment: Then the URL would be something like `/InterviewManagement/SavePanel`? Do you have any custom routing?

Comment: My error code is definetly 500 internal server error. When I look at the response it says what I said in my post. I thought maybe that I need an attribute for my method like an equivilant to [httpget] but I am using JSON verb and not a get or post.

Comment: Beside the routing problem, you're using `Json()` in the wrong way, you should pass an object (not your own prepared JSON) and the method would serialize it to JSON. In your case: `return Json(new { success: true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`.

Comment: I would guess it's `InterviewManagementDataLayer` responsible for the exception.

Comment: @DavidG, There's no HTTP verb named "JSON".

Comment: The person who posted an answer but then deleted it was right. I changed the url to  url: '/InterviewManagement/SavePanel', and it now works. I guess because I can't use razor to get a relative path I need to hardcode the whole thing. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: I think the `The method or operation is not implemented` is caused by the invalid HTTP verb used (`JSON` instead of `GET` or `POST`), see the `jQuery.ajax` call. Thanks to @DavidG who spotted this.

Comment: There are several tricks to inject the current server root path into your jquery (via injected page attributes using `@Url.Content("~/")`), so that it will run on web applications too.

Comment: @Ufuk Hacıoğulları : You might as well restore your answer (and tweak the `type`) as you worked it out first :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie No, you hurt my feelings :/

Comment: @Ufuk Hacıoğulları: Don't be a baby. Take my upvote like a man :)

Answer (score 1):

You are writing your ajax in wrong way. You haven't defined the .ajax type, whether it is Post or Get. Try to write your ajax like:

```
   $.ajax({
   url: '/InterviewManagement/SavePanel',
   dataType: "json",
    type: "POST", 
    data: {
        chairId: panelIds[0],
        coPanelistId: panelIds[1]
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#InterviewManagementFrm').html(data);
    }
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to give the complete URL path for it to work. Because my JS is in an external script I don't have razor available to me to get a virtual path. I ended up making this change.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/InterviewManagement/SavePanel',
            data: {
                chairId: panelIds[0],
                coPanelistId: panelIds[1]
            },
            type: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#InterviewManagementFrm').html(data);
            }
        });
```

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: As spotted by @DavidG, you're using `type: 'json'` incorrectly, there's no 'JSON' HTTP verb, change it to `type: 'post'`.

Comment: To support different hosting paths, inject your root path into the master page (e.g. as a data attribute) using `@Url.Content("~/")`. Your JS can then pick it up for any requests and prepend to the urls.